# Absolute Center Content Without Setting Height

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
 background-color: gold;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
}
.child {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 padding: .8em 1.2em;
 color: white;
 background-color: darkcyan;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
  <div class="group">
  <div class="left parent">
    <div class="child">
      <h1>helo</h1>
      <span>hi again</span> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="videoWrapper"> 
      <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
      <iframe width="560" height="600" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

My content is centered, but I would like it to take it the full height on the "group" class. Here is a live link. velnikolic.com/alohaSpeed I am open to other suggestions as I know this is only one way of doing things, but I found it to be the only working code for some reason.

Comment: You will always need to have a height for the parent, otherwise what would be the value of `top:50%`?

Answer (score 1):

Without height you can't absolute the `content` , you have to set the parent div height 100% or some value of height what ever you need , now i just Remove the `transform property` and set top value using`calc()`

```css
.parent {
 background-color: gold;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
}
.child {
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(50% - 65px);
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: .8em 1.2em;
 color: white;
 background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="left parent">
    <div class="child">
      <h1>helo</h1>
      <span>hi again</span> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="videoWrapper"> 
      <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
      <iframe width="560" height="600" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flex box styling to do this (jsFiddle below). You can then change the height values to percentages if you desired (I wasn't sure if that's something you wanted to do or not).

```css
.parent {
 background-color: gold;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
}
.child {
 
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: .8em 1.2em;
 color: white;
 background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="left parent">
    <div class="child">
      <h1>helo</h1>
      <span>hi again</span> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="videoWrapper"> 
      <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
      <iframe width="560" height="600" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm. when I set the height too 100% it takes the height of the content inside it. Is there a way to way to make it take the height of the "group" div so it's responsive (like the video)